# bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent

Tags: transactions, signrawtransaction, sendrawtransaction

I want to sign btc transaction but when I want to broadcast trx to network even mainnet nor testnet, with both networks I got the same error.:
bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent
"error": { "code": -25, "message": "bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent" },
UTXOS of the account.

```
{ "address": "bc1qfhndl48dpng7vlwltmyq7ulnggk68nzcjkcj5z", "total_received": 459522, "total_sent": 0, "balance": 459522, "unconfirmed_balance": 0, "final_balance": 459522, "n_tx": 2, "unconfirmed_n_tx": 0, "final_n_tx": 2, "txrefs": [ { "tx_hash": "9d8c4d07f003ba9854e0c90adbd2c5e0d3bb60cb81a818b727d4a67675902173", "block_height": 718010, "tx_input_n": -1, "tx_output_n": 0, "value": 359522, "ref_balance": 459522, "spent": false, "confirmations": 3, "confirmed": "2022-01-10T11:49:43Z", "double_spend": false, "script": "00144de6dfd4ed0cd1e67ddf5ec80f73f3422da3cc58" }, { "tx_hash": "59de87c51b51ca0b5b1ecb8b3868319fcd0df58c40f61a5c7c66e2c7ae39dd66", "block_height": 717924, "tx_input_n": -1, "tx_output_n": 0, "value": 100000, "ref_balance": 100000, "spent": false, "confirmations": 89, "confirmed": "2022-01-09T22:41:15Z", "double_spend": false, "script": "00144de6dfd4ed0cd1e67ddf5ec80f73f3422da3cc58" } ] }
```

hex raw : `0100000000010166dd39aec7e2667c5c1af6408cf50dcd9f3168388bcb1e5b0bca511bc587de5902000000000000000002204e000000000000160014e0d31f509e0939975bcb41ca32e03da24f82828432350100000000001600144de6dfd4ed0cd1e67ddf5ec80f73f3422da3cc580248304502210080c0035b0a0128b82a2a20851204a5d039d9778a16e4bec8cbdd8fc744e9b29402202bc5bbaba90c146f213409feaec0671b62ecc3001b47f11fc3686332c3578df101210308dd04bcd865b7219fe683ff3a94470f99222686c28caa91a8d775b06da669b700000000`

decoded trx:

```
{ "txid": "0ff84c4e6bebfa77d009f8f978668e2cbe7eebb52b5a7328af7393e3dea45d3d", 
  "hash": "e080aa3cf21c780c0cc34a4ef5ba35589f964a9329a519906673ec24a1b373e3",
  "version": 1, 
  "size": 223, 
  "vsize": 141, 
  "weight": 562, 
  "locktime": 0, 
  "vin": [ { 
    "txid": "59de87c51b51ca0b5b1ecb8b3868319fcd0df58c40f61a5c7c66e2c7ae39dd66", 
    "vout": 2, 
    "scriptSig": { "asm": "", "hex": "" }, 
    "txinwitness": [ "304502210080c0035b0a0128b82a2a20851204a5d039d9778a16e4bec8cbdd8fc744e9b29402202bc5bbaba90c146f213409feaec0671b62ecc3001b47f11fc3686332c3578df101", "0308dd04bcd865b7219fe683ff3a94470f99222686c28caa91a8d775b06da669b7" ], 
    "sequence": 0 } ],
  "vout": [ { 
    "value": 0.0002, 
    "n": 0, 
    "scriptPubKey": { 
      "asm": "0 e0d31f509e0939975bcb41ca32e03da24f828284", 
      "hex": "0014e0d31f509e0939975bcb41ca32e03da24f828284", 
      "address": "bc1qurf375y7pyuewk7tg89r9cpa5f8c9q5y7dagzv", 
      "type": "witness_v0_keyhash" } 
  }, { "
    value": 0.00079154, 
    "n": 1, 
    "scriptPubKey": { 
      "asm": "0 4de6dfd4ed0cd1e67ddf5ec80f73f3422da3cc58", 
      "hex": "00144de6dfd4ed0cd1e67ddf5ec80f73f3422da3cc58",
      "address": "bc1qfhndl48dpng7vlwltmyq7ulnggk68nzcjkcj5z",
      "type": "witness_v0_keyhash" } 
    } 
  ] }
```

The func I used for sign btc signner:

```
private fun signBTC() {

if (::btcTransactionFee.isInitialized.not()) return

val amount= BigDecimal(getExtAmount()).multiply(BigDecimal(1E8)).toLong()


val coinBtc: CoinType = CoinType.BITCOIN


val toAddress=getExtRecipientAddress()

val script = BitcoinScript.lockScriptForAddress(coinKey.address, coinBtc).data()
var i =0;

val input = Bitcoin.SigningInput.newBuilder().apply {
    this.amount = amount
    this.hashType = BitcoinSigHashType.ALL.value()
    this.toAddress = toAddress
    this.changeAddress = coinKey.address
    this.byteFee = 6
    this.coinType = coinBtc.value()
    this.addPrivateKey(coinKey.privateKey)
}
for (buff in btcUtxos.items) {
    i += 1;
    val txHash = buff.txHash.toHexBytes()
    txHash.reverse()
    val outPoint = Bitcoin.OutPoint.newBuilder().apply {
        this.hash = ByteString.copyFrom(txHash)
        this.index = i
    }.build()
    val utxo = Bitcoin.UnspentTransaction.newBuilder().apply {
        this.amount = buff.value.toBigDecimal().toLong()
        this.outPoint = outPoint
        this.script = ByteString.copyFrom(script)
    }.build()

    input.addUtxo(utxo);
}
val plan = AnySigner.plan(input.build(), coinBtc, Bitcoin.TransactionPlan.parser())
input.plan = plan
input.amount = plan.amount
val output = AnySigner.sign(input.build(), coinBtc, Bitcoin.SigningOutput.parser())

val encoded = output.encoded

val signedTransaction = Numeric.toHexString(encoded.toByteArray()).substring(2)
btcViewModel.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction)
```

}